# Copying a chunk of output in Windows 7

Tags: windows-command-prompt, findstr

I'm wondering how to copy a chunk of output in the command prompt in Windows 7.  What I'm ultimately trying to accomplish is when I type "route print" I want to copy the IPs listed under IPv4 Route Table.  I used the findstr command to grab 1 line at a time but is there a way to grab the whole table in one shot?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this is getting pretty ugly but seems to work, somehow:

```
route print -4 | findstr /r /c:"^  *[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\."
```

This yields the complete IPv4 routing table for me, excluding the interface list.

You may be better off running it through `for /f`, though and just count the number of lines that consist solely of `=` signs to know where you are in the output.

Answer (score 3):

"grab" in what sense?

Would piping the output to a file be useful? 
e,g.

c:\route print > test.txt

Answer (score 3):

You can copy the output directly into your windows clipboard by 'piping' to 'clip'

so your command would look like this:

```
route print | clip
```

You can then paste in notepad, etc.

You can also manually copy pieces to the clipboard by right-clicking the window, selecting 'mark' then dragging across an area. While the area is highlighted, the clipboard will contain a copy of that area.

Answer (score 1):

Try using powershell. You can do a lot more with that. There may be a better way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

c:>route print > rprint.txt

c:>notepad rprint.txt

Comment: This is technically correct, but the downvote is probably for the brevity.  (It wasn't me.)